# How to reverse Fourier Transform on an image with np.fft.ifft2 - Python

Tags: python, image, signal-processing, fft

I am new to Fourier Transform in Python.

I want to isolate a field on an image thanks to Fourier Transform. Here is my picture :

[image]

And here is what I am supposed to obtain :

[image]

Here is my code until now :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

path = "C:/Users/cecil/OneDrive/Bureau/00_TP_M2TSI/TP Traitement Image/BE1 PDF/BE1 PDF/champs.png"

img = plt.imread(path)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #converting to grayscale


plt.set_cmap("gray")
plt.subplot(131)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis("off")

# Calculate the Fourier transform of the grating
ft = np.fft.ifftshift(img)
ft = np.fft.fft2(ft)
ft = np.fft.fftshift(ft)
plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(np.log(abs(ft)))
plt.axis("off")
    
#isolating the band we want to keep (we define 2 affine functions to border the band and keep only the 
    # values that are inbetween)
for x in range(0,512): 
    y1 = 0.77*x + 55
    y2 = 0.77*x + 65
    for y in range(0,512):
        if not(y > y1 and y < y2) : 
            ft[y,x] = 0

            
# Calculate the inverse Fourier transform of 
# the Fourier transform
ift = np.fft.ifftshift(ft)
ift = np.fft.ifft2(ift)
ift = np.fft.fftshift(ift)
ift = ift.real  # Take only the real part

plt.subplot(133)
plt.imshow(ift)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

My problem is I obtain this image instead of the one I want (see above) :

[image]

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here? You are cutting out one of the main branches (top left to bottom right) in the frequency domain, and hoping to get the full image in a smaller area? The filter will give you all structures that belong to that frequency (here the sharp edges from bottom left to top right). So the result of the inverse FFT is as sexpected.

Comment: well i was trying to isolate the line of the spectrum of the log fft (the one you talked about, from top left to bottom right) as it corresponds to the direction of the lines in my field, thus to my field (roughly). I was surprised as there shouldn't be so much lines in the same direction, or at least I should obtain more of those in the field area. But it's ok I figured out how to do what I wanted, thank you !

Comment: “How to reverse Fourier Transform on an image” — you’re doing it right, you just have the wrong expectation for the operation.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I fixed the problem. It seems I actually needed to do the shift and fft and ishift and ifft in segragated lines like this :

```
# Calculate the Fourier transform of the grating
spectre = fft2(imgris)
spectre = fftshift(spectre)
plt.imshow(np.log(abs(spectre)))
plt.show()

bande = np.zeros((512,512), dtype=complex)

for x in range(0,512): 
    y1 = 0.77*x + 40
    y2 = 0.77*x + 80
    for y in range(0,512):
        if y > y1 and y < y2 : 
            bande[y,x] = spectre[y,x]
        if x > (512/2-20) and x < (512/2+20):
            bande[y,x] = 0
            
plt.imshow(abs(bande))
plt.show()

real = bande.real
phases = bande.imag
bande_mod = np.empty(real.shape, dtype=complex)
bande_mod.real = real
bande_mod.imag = phases

champisolé= ifftshift(bande_mod)
champisolé= np.abs(ifft2(champisolé))

plt.imshow(champisolé)
plt.show()
```

The obtained image (first picture) is kinda blurred and there is quite a lot of unwanted pixels around the field I wanted to isolate but with a few filters I obtain a perfectly isolated field (even better than the teacher's !) (second picture).

[image]

[image]